# Windows 10 does not wake up from a sleep state

Tags: windows-10, sleep

I have windows 10 in Toshiba laptop, when it is in sleep state, I am not able to wake it up.

I try evething: mobig the mouse pressing many buttons, but no way.

does someone has any idea how can i solve this ?

Comment: We need some more information. What Laptop model is it? Did waking it up once work? Maybe you have used Windows 7 without the problem on the same machine?

Answer (score -1):

I personally had the same problem with a windows 7 device for a old desktop, buts I had managed to solve it, kind of. I don't think you'd like it, but it'll probably work. I usually pull out the power chord on the back of the computer, but since yours is a laptop, removing the power source of some kind like a battery might help.I think by removing the power source it resets the computer, releasing from the weird sleeping phase.

*By the way I usually had that problem only when I used a sleep button that's on my keyboard.So this may not solve your problem since its probably a different kind of cause I'm guessing.

If you find any solution to this, just please tell me for I am also interested in what might cause or solve problems like this. Thanks!